# Adding System.IO.Compression Assembly Reference to Mono CentOS

Tags: c#, dll, mono, .net-assembly, centos7

I am trying to make use of the System.IO.Compression DLL in my C# application running on CentOS 7 with Mono 5.2.0.215.

I was able to add the assembly reference in Visual Studio, but when I try to compile the .cs, it's throwing an error:

> Program.cs(48,21): error CS0103: The name `ZipFile' does not exist in the current context
>   Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

ZipFile being a class of the assembly reference.

Any idea how to make this work?

```
foreach(var file in piesZipList)
        {
            try
            {
                string extractionPath = file.Substring(0, file.LastIndexOf('.') - 1);
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(file, extractionPath);
                piesUnzippedList.Add(extractionPath);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please add Code, to see a possible problem.

Comment: `using System.IO.Compression;`

Comment: @Gusman, adding this that line does not fix the problem, as it is already in the solution. The problem is, the Assembly reference is not included by default in mono. I need to know how to add it.

Comment: @Nikolaus, I have added a block of code

Comment: Does your File contain the using of Gusman?

Comment: Which .net-Version do you use?

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I tried. And 4.5

Comment: Also, why is this downvoted? I am just trying to get an answer from a site that answers questions. Now this will receive no new views. Sweeet.

Comment: Which Version of Visual Studio do you use?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Nikolaus, No not yet, and I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community. I was able to get the assembly reference by adding it via the solution explorer is VS. But I cant figure out how to add it to Mono